# Problem to Install pyspark of version 2.3

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I was trying to install pyspark 2.3 from the last couple days. But I have found out Version 3.0.1 and 2.4.7 only so far. Actually I was trying to run a code implemented in pyspark 2.3 as a part of my project.  Is that version still available now ? Please send me the essential resources to install pyspark 2.3 if it is available to install as well as shareable.  As it seems tough to me to implement that code in version 3.0.1.

Comment: There shouldn't be major changes between 2.3 and 2.4.7 ... And the basic functions haven't changed much to version 3, so what errors were you running into?

Answer (score 0):

Pyspark 2.3 should still be available via Conda-Forge.

Please checkout https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyspark/files?version=2.3.2

There you will find the following and more packages for a direct download:

- linux-64/pyspark-2.3.2-py36_1000.tar.bz2
- win-64/pyspark-2.3.2-py36_1000.tar.bz2

If you don't want the raw packages, you can also install it via conda:

```py
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark=2.3.2
```